# How to Get The Distinct Data From SQL in the Following Scenario?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Menu` having recursive one to many relationship.
The table contains menu and its sub-menu.

When I execute the query I get the result:

```
->Form.....Activity
->Form.....Report
->Review..Activity
->Review..Report
```

But I want to store this information in C# collections (List/Dictionary) as in the following format.

```
->Form
  Activity
  Report
->Review
  Activity
  Report
```

Note: I am using SQL-Data-Reader in C# to retrieve the information from SQL Server 2008.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Include the query and the code you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not code I'll explain my answer in words.

You can use dictionary or hashtable to store the data using C#.

Using Dictionary:

Declare a Dictionary that will store key and list of values i.e.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>  dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> ();
```

Then when you query return data you can do the following. Say you reading data from the DataTable.

```
 Foreach(DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows)
 {
      if(dicData.ContainsKey(row["firstColumn"]))
      {
         dicData[row["firstColumn"].ToString()].Add(row["secondColumn"].ToString());
      }
      else
      {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
         list.Add(row["secondColumn"].ToString())

         dicData.Add(row["firstColumn"].ToString(), list)
      }
 }
```

**NB:** The code is not tested but it will give you an idea of what you need to do. Hope it helps